# Working Directory is not a Cordova-based project from Grunt

Tags: cordova, gruntjs

I have a web-app that I build via Grunt. Now, I want to bundle that app as part of my build process using PhoneGap/Cordova. In an attempt to do that, I've included the grunt-cordovacli module and have a target called 'deploy'. Deploy is setup like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
  'build',
  'cordovacli:add_platforms',
  'cordovacli:add_plugins', 
  'cordovacli:prepare_ios',
  'cordovacli:prepare_android', 
  'cordovacli:prepare_windows',
  'cordovacli:build_ios',
  'cordovacli:build_android',
  'cordovacli:build_windows'
]);
```

I've confirmed build works by loading the content in my browser. My cordovacli task is configured as follows:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  return {
    options: {
      path: '/distribute'
    },
    cordova: {
      options: {
        command: ['prepare', 'create','platform','plugin','build'],
        platforms: ['ios','android', 'wp8'],
        plugins: ['device','dialogs'],
        path: '/distribute',
        id: 'myco.myapp',
        name: 'myapp'
      }
    }
    add_platforms: {
      options: {
        command: 'platform',
        action: 'add',
        platforms: ['ios', 'android', 'wp8']
      }
    },
    add_plugins: {
      options: {
        command: 'plugin',
        action: 'add',
        plugins: [
          'battery-status',
          'camera',
          'contacts',
          'splashscreen'
        ]
      }
    },
    build_ios: {
      options: {
        command: 'build',
        platforms: ['ios']
      }
    },
    build_android: {
      options: {
        command: 'build',
        platforms: ['android']
      }
    },
    build_windows: {
      options: {
        command: 'build',
        platforms: ['wp8']
      }
    },
    prepare_ios: {
      options: {
        command: 'prepare',
        platforms: ['ios']
      }
    },
    prepare_android: {
      options: {
        command: 'prepare',
        platforms: ['android']
      }
    }
  };
};
```

When I run deploy, everything works up until the cordova stuff. At that point, I get the following:

```
Running "cordovacli:add_platforms" (cordovacli) task
Using cordova CLI version (3.5.0-0.2.6)
Setting Current Working Directory (CWD) to distribute
Running:node C:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\grunt-cordovacli\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova platform add ios
Running:node C:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\grunt-cordovacli\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova platform add android
Running:node C:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\grunt-cordovacli\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova platform add wp8
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
>> Error
Error-> with Parallel tasksError
```

What is wrong with this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check does your app folder contains .cordova folder(hidden)

Comment: as per my understanding the `cordova add` command should be run within the project folder. This is what the error states as well `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`. Is the `C:\Projects\myapp\...cordova\bin\` a cordova based project folder?

Comment: Is there a way to run cordova add via grunt? Perhaps the user could use grunt-exec. I'm interested to know if grunt-cordovacli has a initialization type task that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are not running the initial `create` cordovacli task so the project does not exist and therefore cannot add platforms.

Cordova knows you have not created an app because `config.xml` does not exist in `/distribute` path.

Also make sure you do not have a `config.xml` in the same directory as the `grunfile.js` otherwise for some reason, platforms get added there and not in your specified `/distribute` path. I was stuck figuring this out for a while.